# How can I fill the camera's frustum with fix sized cubes?

Tags: math, three.js, 3d, geometry, frustum

I believe this would be a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_of_irregular_objects) of a trapezoid (camera's frustum). I want to fill the entire camera's frustum with fix sized cubes or cuboids. I need a set of cubes that fit within the camera's frustum every time the camera is moved. It is **important** that these cubes are axis-aligned in the world space, because otherwise there would be a lot of overlapping and I have to avoid this for my use-case.

My initial thought was to create a considerable high number (higher than the world size) of cubes looping from an initial point `p=(0,0,0)`, make p the center of a cube and if the size is 2, then place `p2=(2,0,0)` as the center point for the next cube, `p3=(0,2,0)` for the third and so on... 
The problem with this is that I will add to the scene a larger number of cubes than I really need, and every time I move the camera I will have to traverse through all the cubes to check whether they intersect or are contained within the camera's frustum, I believe this approach could be very expensive.

How could I do this, is there a smarter way to do this?.

On a side note, if the packaging problem could be done with variable sized 3D quadrilaterals, would it be an easier problem to solve? And how to do it?

**Edit:** I'm having a hard time understanding camera space vs camera world in some cases. I tried your approach but instead of considering the layers I created my own layers "artificially" and instead of transforming the cuboids using the inverse view matrix I'm getting the max/min points of the cuboids to get a bounding box in world space (I believe this is true).

```html
this.createCuboids = (farCamera, xDist, yDist, nearPoints) => {
  //xDist is the difference of max.x and min.x
  //yDist is the difference of max.y and min.y
  //nearPoints are 4 points that represent the near plane
  const cuboidsCount = 5; //number of layers
  const cuboidThickness = farCamera/cuboidsCount; //depth for each layer

  let cuboidList = [];

  for (let i=1; i < cuboidsCount+1; i++) {
      const cuboid = [
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[0].x, nearPoints[0].y, nearPoints[0].z),  // nearTopLeft
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[1].x, nearPoints[1].y, nearPoints[1].z),  // nearBottomRight
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[2].x, nearPoints[2].y, nearPoints[2].z),  // nearTopRight
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[3].x, nearPoints[3].y, nearPoints[3].z),  // nearBottomLeft
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[0].x+xDist*i, nearPoints[0].y+yDist*i, nearPoints[0].z+cuboidThickness*i), // farTopLeft
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[1].x+xDist*i, nearPoints[1].y+yDist*i, nearPoints[1].z+cuboidThickness*i), // farBottomRight
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[2].x+xDist*i, nearPoints[2].y+yDist*i, nearPoints[2].z+cuboidThickness*i), // farTopRight
          new THREE.Vector3(nearPoints[3].x+xDist*i, nearPoints[3].y+yDist*i, nearPoints[3].z+cuboidThickness*i), // farBottomLeft
      ];
      cuboidList.push(cuboid);
  }
  //Finally get the X/Y/Z max and min as bounding box for each cuboid
```

I'm interested to know if my code is equivalent to yours. The thing is that when creating the layers from the camera, and then translating them to the world space, most of them are overlapping when the camera is not aligned with the world axes, and this is not good because I would be querying the database very inefficiently. The next image shows the yellow part of two cuboids overlapping.

[image]

Hence, I'm trying a different approach where I get my initial bounding box of the frustum (in world space) and then start to split the bigger cuboid in 8 smaller ones until a certain number of "mini-cubes" and depth is reached. If a cuboid is inside the frustum we take it as a good cuboid and stop the split. In the same way if the cuboid is outside the frustum we discard it. The next image tries to show this.

[image]

This would be the piece of code for this approach.

```html
// Given a bounding box of the frustum, create a cuboid mesh of depth d (recursive version)
this.createCuboidMeshRecursive = (cube, depth) => {
    // chill, too deep
    if (depth > 3) return;
    // this one is outside, discard it
    else if (!this.frustum.intersectsBox(cube)) return;
    // this one is inside, add it
    else if (this.frustum.intersectsBox(cube)) {
        this.cuboidMeshRecursive.push(cube);
        return;
    }
    else {
        this.auxBounding.set(cube.min,cube.max);
        const manyCubes = this.splitCube();
        manyCubes.forEach(subbox => {
            this.createCuboidMeshRecursive(subbox, depth+1);
        });
    }
};
```

**Final edit:** With this recursive function you can create a cuboid mesh that fills the frustum, with a desired depth. `frustum.intersectsBox` is not enough to decide whether a cuboid should be discarded or not. I had to implement it according to my needs.

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for? I have the feeling that there is a better solution for what you want. If not, what are the characteristics of the cubes? Will they always be at integer positions? Or can they move arbitrarily?

Comment: I want to perform spatial queries to a backend to load 3 dimensional points that are located (in the space) within the camera's frustum, I cannot perform queries in the shape of a trapezoid, only cubes or regular 3D quadrilaterals. To solve this I can perform multiple smaller queries in the shape of cubes/quadrilaterals that follow the shape of the trapezoid (camera's frustum). Smaller cubes allow a higher precision I assume.

Comment: Are cuboids also fine? Then, you would just need one cuboid per depth layer, which is significantly less. The layer thickness will in the end determine your accuracy.

Comment: Yes, cuboids are fine. I'm looking at https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Layers How do I set the thickness of each layer? If this Layers class allows me to divide the camera's frustum in slices (cuboids) it would solve my problem. But I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: What is wrong with your second approach? One thing that I see is that your intersection test is off. A cube can intersect a frustum even if none of its vertices lie inside the frustum. Use `frustum.intersectsBox()` instead. However, it dies not tell you if the intersection is partial. You probably need to write your own function for that.

Comment: I think the while condition is wrong, I'm always checking for the last element in cuboidsToCheck and the while will break after reaching a max depth (I believe) discarding the pending cuboids. About the intersection test you're right, haven't thought of that. Will check it tomorrow and update, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is also another thing. Usually, you do this recursively in the form: `fillWithCubes(box) { if box is outside then return; if box is inside then add box and return; else for each subbox in split(box): fillWithCubes(subbox)`. Of course, with an appropriate call depth limit.